# add ntfs-3g to tinycore live usb without internet access

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I add the package ntfs-3g to an existing live usb drive without having access to internet.
I want to somehow download it and put it on the usb drive and install it though the terminal when the computer is booted with tinycore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download any package you want from http://tinycorelinux.net/7.x/x86/tcz/ and place it in `/cde/optional/` on your USB. Optionally add package name to `onboot.lst`.